# Display latest 100 posts with pagination of 5 posts per page in wordpress using WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

My website has more than 5000 posts and I am trying to display the latest 100 posts in a separate page with pagination(5 posts per page).

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
endwhile;
the_posts_navigation(); 
wp_reset_postdata();
else :
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
endif;
?>
```

I am using the above code which displays 5 posts per page but I could find a way to restrict the total posts count to 100. I went through various blog articles and various SO threads but couldn't find any solution for this.

There were few threads that say, using 'numberposts' => 100 will help. But that didn't help either.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the limit as like:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => $paged
);
if($args['posts_per_page'] * $args['paged'] <= 100){
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
    endwhile;
    the_posts_navigation(); 
    wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Manash. 
The result is as I expected. Is this a standard technique or some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );        
    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('< Previous'),
            'next_text'    => __('Next >'),
        ));
    }    
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I am looking for a solution using normal the_posts_navigation(); as I am using Infinite Scroll plugin to load posts on the scroll which overrides the default WordPress pagination.